# dotnet build produces NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I made a change to a known working project and now I get the following when building with `dotnet build`:

```
λ dotnet build
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The change was adding a new framework to the `frameworks` section, which has worked in the past. I'm not sure why it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3075) in the dotnet CLI. It happens if you add a new framework to `project.json` but don't run `dotnet restore`.

Restoring first fixes the issue:

```
λ dotnet restore

log  : Restore completed in 2138ms.

λ dotnet build

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```